# Menu Contextual Order

Tags: navigation, menu, information-architecture, ordering

The application I'm working on maintains lists of timezones, countries, cities, & venues, and it allows the user to manage those lists (list/add/edit/remove) via a menu.

My initial approach was to create a menu header 'Locations' and list the data types in the order above, thereby providing the user a visual representation of the context of the data they're working with.  The menu items become increasingly more specific as you go down the list.

It occurs to me however that the frequency with which the user will need to manage these data types is the inverse - they will need to manage venues much more often than timezones.  This would suggest inverting the menu order to put the most frequently accessed item at the top.

When doing this however, the sense of context is somewhat lost and it feels less intuitive.

Has anyone conducted any studies or have any experience that would guide such a decision between these two alternatives?

Comment: If you can provide an actual mockup of the current menu design you are considering might help in understanding your problem better.

Comment: Can you provide an image / wireframe as the description is somewhat confusing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any user interviews? I would try some variations on your design and get some feedback from people in a cafe or someplace.

After reading your description, my suggestion would be to make "venues" it's own menu item that takes users straight to the venue management interface (only one click required) then put the cities, countries and timezones under something like "location settings"

..just a thought.

An image of your interface and some context about who uses your app and what they are trying to accomplish would be helpful to put your question in context.